# Problemas em criar media queries para Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout-responsivo, media-queries

Estou desenvolvendo um site responsivo e nele defini algumas marcações de CSS com *media queries*, porém ainda sofro com alguns dispositivos, como exemplo, o *Samsung Galaxy S4*. Acredito que seja pelo fato dele conter um `device-pixel-ratio` igual a 3. Queria saber como faço pra definir media queries pra esse tipo de dispositivo.

[image: Emulação do dispositivo Samsung Galaxy S4 no Chrome DevTools]

Usando [Twitter Bootstrap](http://www.getbootstrap.com) a coisa fica incrivelmente mais fácil, pois ele se adapta a qualquer dispositivo, inclusive no S4, que tem um `device-pixel-ratio` "diferente". Acontece que o site já está pronto, refatorar está fora de cogitação.

Existem outros dispositivos que possam me dar dor de cabeça? Devo apenas adicionar uma media query diferente para o dispositivo Samsung Galaxy S4, ou existe alguma forma de fazer com que meu CSS fique semelhante ao [Twitter Bootstrap](http://www.getbootstrap.com)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O ideal seria a refatoração, pois ajustar seu layout para dispositivos específicos é considerada uma prática ruim.

Sem mais informações a respeito de que tipo de problemas você encontra, acredito que você deverá usar media queries específicas. De acordo com [esta lista](http://cssmediaqueries.com/target/), as regras CSS para o S4 devem constar na seguinte media query:

```
@media screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 640px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
```

E atente-se ao fato de que essa regra ainda é limitada a navegadores WebKit, pela presença da propriedade prefixada `-webkit-device-pixel-ratio`.